# Multiple individual ajax calls VS one call with pairs of data

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm not exactly "stuck" on a problem, but would rather like to know which is best practice between sending a single ajax call with a dataset to be handled by the controller, or looping through each input field (up to 100 of them) and sending one ajax call for each.

Here is what my table looks like, it's built using bootstrap.

[image: My table example]

When the user clicks on a cell of that table, it generates an input field inside the cell. The cell has data properties allowing me to know exactly which row and column it belongs to.

Once the user clicks on a Save button, it needs to submit the data from the active input fields on the page to my database.

**My current options are:**

1. Use $.each() and send one ajax request per filled cell.
2. Use $.each() to fill a variable containing all the key-value pairs, and then send it through a single ajax request.

I've never done the second, but I'm fairly confident it can be done without too much trouble.

My question is:

**What are the pros and cons** of each method?

I'm curious about the impacts on performance, and other aspects I might be overlooking.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Do you submit the data when the user clicks on a "Save" button or you're doing it when any data field is changed?

Comment: It is submitted using a Save button, I'll add that detail to the question!